# bs4 Extract text from a list of <tags> as <span> or <b> and save it on excel

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm new to bs4 and I'm searching a way to extract text from a page, then add it on an Excel file, after then going to the next page and finally add the new text to the already created Excel file.
This is my result

```
from selenium import webdriver
import scrapy
import datetime
import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

geckodriver = "#here lies the path#"
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, 

firefox_options=options)
link= "a result page from booking such as [this][1]"
driver.get(link)
pageSource = driver.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
HotelNames = bs.select('.sr-hotel__name')
HotelScores = bs.select('.review-score-badge')
HotelPrices = prezziHotel = bs.findAll("b")
```

The list is similar to this print

```
print(HotelNames)
[<span class="sr-hotel__name " data-et-click="
customGoal:NAFLWCAHUJMDDWEYcZbBJOTXNORe:1
">
Residence Adam's Apple
</span>, <span class="sr-hotel__name " data-et-click="
customGoal:NAFLWCAHUJMDDWEYcZbBJOTXNORe:1
">
La Luna
</span>, <span class="sr-hotel__name " data-et-click="
">
Hotel Astor
</span>,
```

Using

```
HotelNames = HotelNames.get_text()
```

or extract gives the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-01e95302c548> in <module>()
----> 1 nomeHotel = nomiHotel.getText()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Personally, I don't know what to do. The only result I have lists with the tag  or . If I could grab only the text I need (the name of all the hotel, the rating of all the hotels and the price is shown) then I could add it on an Excel file.

For the Excel part, I'm going to do the following code

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Hotels.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
rowName = 1
rowScore=1
rowPrice=1
col = 0
for name in (HotelNames):
    worksheet.write(rowName, 0, name)
    rowName += 1
for score in (HotelScores):
    worksheet.write(rowScore, 0, name)
    rowScore += 1
for price in (HotelPrices):
    worksheet.write(rowPrice, 0, name)
    rowPrice += 1
```

Thanks for all the help!

The first part of the problem is solved thanks to the help of [Sarthak Negi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8123710/sarthak-negi) and [Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549554/andersson)
the following code was used and worked

```
i=0
HotelListNameWithoutTags = []
for name in HotelNames:
        HotelListNameWithoutTags.append(HotelNames[i].get_text())
        i=i+1
print(HotelListNameWithoutTags)
for name in HotelListNameWithoutTags:
    print(name)
```

but also this other code worked

```
HotelNames = [name.get_text() for name in HotelNames]
```

Now there is a second minor issue with this extraction. The result in both of case are similar to these outputs:

```
Hotel Atlas


Residence Adam's Apple
```

this happens when I print a single row. When I print HotelListNameWithoutTags the following output appears:

```
['\nHotel Atlas\n', "\nResidence Adam's Apple\n",
```

[Martin Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4985733/martin-evans) helped giving the following code

HotelNames = [name.replace('\n', '') for name in HotelNames]

now I have the last part of this project. I) have to change page using the navigation bar in the website that is formed by  tag with href and text. The problem that are very "nested"

```
<div class="bui-pagination results-paging">
     <div class="bui-pagination__nav">
          <ul class="bui-pagination__list">
               <li class="bui-pagination__pages">
                    <ul class="bui-pagination__list">
                         <li class="bui-pagination__item bui-pagination__item--active sr_pagination_item current">
                              <a class="bui-pagination__link sr_pagination_link" href="link">1</a>
</closing tags>
```

How can I grab the href or the text in  tag (Using the name of the class with select doesn't work at all. There are many  in the page, so I can't use find_All method as well)

Comment: Try `HotelNames = [name.get_text() for name in HotelNames]`

Comment: get_text is a bs4 method...and you are trying get_text on a list...do HotelNames[0].get_text() (depending on the length), you will get the text inside it

Comment: also for hotel names and all other data go loop inside the HotelNames and convert them to text then

Comment: Good! Now we are near the result. The tag <span> there aren't anymore.
but now there is '\nHotel Atlas\n' that I think is referred to as the "enter" (\n)
I need to get rid of this \n and probably also of the ' that stand before and after. I was going to think to drop the first 3 characters and the last 3. There is a better solution?

Comment: Try `HotelNames = [name.get_text().replace('\n', ' ').strip() for name in HotelNames]`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The correct code was HotelNames = [name.replace('\n', '') for name in HotelNames] 
Now there is the last part of this question upthere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the solution used to change page was to discover how many pages there will be there. Then, create a list with the page that will be searched and every time scrape all the data.
Here an example of the creation of the list of links to scrape:

```
driver.get(link)
pages= bs.find_all("span","bui-pagination__info") 
for page in pages:
    page= page.get_text()
```

in this part there I fin how many elements I have in a single page. Sometimes can be 10 elements, but sometimes they can be 20, 30 or even 50. So I cannot know before which number I have to write.

```
page= page[-2:] #I need only the number in my case
page= int(pagina) #I need to be integer

links = bs.find_all("a", "bui-pagination__link sr_pagination_link")

linkNumber=[]
for l in links:
    l = l.get_text()
    linkNumber.append(l)
```

In this way I have the Link that I can use with selenium, but also the number of pages returned. And I need to find the "number" of the last page.

```
ultimoNumeroLink = linkNumero[-1]
ultimoNumeroLink = int(ultimoNumeroLink)

numeroMassimoElementi = ultimoNumeroLink * pagina
```

And using the last multiplication I can find how many elements will be there in my research.